# Using the Delphi Mock Framework and causing side effects

Tags: delphi, mocking, delphi-xe2, delphi-mocks

I am using the rather good [Delphi Mocks](http://www.finalbuilder.com/Resources/Blogs/PostId/417/Introducing-Delphi-Mocks.aspx) Framework, and am trying to create a Mock of a class that contains a method that has 'side-effects', i.e. it is a read operation, and in the real-world implementation it sets the contents of a buffer, if the read is successful. So my question is, how do I mock that 'side-effect'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WillExecute method on the mock and pass in a delegate (see Delphi.Mocks.pas for it's signature) that does whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was trying to do too much as once, and seem to have an issue when objects pass parameters to constructors.